# NGXS dispatch not calling action

Tags: angular, firebase, state, ngxs

I have been trying to set up NGXS state management with one e-commerce store I am making in Angular with Firebase as a backend.
My state initializes as you see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jSZJ.png).

Sadly I receive no message whatsoever when I try to dispatch an action from my auth-service.

The only changes I've made to the implementation of the state was to add an @Injectable decorator to my states when I export them out of their respective files.

I am not sure whether this is causing an issue, as I have received no error callback since I started debugging.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEfWD.png) is where I call the dispatch.

[Here](https://github.com/MegaBurek/Rosa-Carter) is the git repository for referencing.

Comment: If you could put a simple reproduction into an online example (ie stackblitz) that would really be helpful!

Comment: Ok I'll do that. I'm a bit new to the community

Comment: So it looks like your actions are firing... However the way you have firebase and your ngxs actions wired up is not a pattern I recommend. I do know that other people do it that way, fire one action that subscribes to firebase's valueChanges, but I don't like that flow. I would rather see firebase changes dispatch actions and those actions update state.

Comment: My actions are not firing though.
You tried running the application?
I am having a difficult time setting up the StackBlitz, it will take some time.

Comment: I'm having a lot import errors when trying to link the repository to the stackblitz, even when trying to recreate the component.
I'm just gonna close this question.

Comment: Yes, I pulled the code locally and ran it. If you put a `debugger;` in the action handler it get's hit. I did dispatch it in the app.component because I couldn't log in.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure to add the 'StoreModule.forFeature()` import to the respective module.

Comment: How? and to where ?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that now in standalone setups we need something like this in your feature's routing

```
export default [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ParentComponent,
    providers: [importProvidersFrom(NgxsModule.forFeature([SomeState, SomeOtherState])), SomeService],
    children: [
    ...
```

If there are more ways to accomplish this please comment.